# Qualified Business Income Deduction (QBI)

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

Where is the Qualified Business Income Deduction (QBI) calculated or deducted? I'm using a free service online, but I'd also like to manually fill out the information to double check that I and the free service is calculating my taxes and deductions correctly.

Comment: how is your business organized?

Comment: Sole proprietorship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a worksheet in the instructions for Form 1040.  Page 37 if you have the same PDF as I do.  (Just did mine last night...)

Comment: And deducted on Form 1040, line 9.